# javascript debugging tool

Tags: javascript, debugging

Could someone suggest some tool or how to configure firebug to display a list of defined variables in separate window.

I want to see variables, when any variable changes it property, at what line of code it have been changes and so on.

Because code becomes pretty big and following all needed variables is pretty hard now.

Have someone seen some tool with such capabilities?

Maybe there is some IDE, that have such functionality?

So basically i need to monitor JavaScript variables at separate window.

Thanks ^_=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open the Firebug pane or window.
2. Click on the "***Script***" tab.
3. On the right-hand pane, click on the "***Watch***" tab.
4. Click the "***New watch expression...***".
5. Type or paste in your variable name.
6. Enjoy!

Comment: Yea great, but it seems i should update it manually :D

Is it possible to watch it in realtime?

Is it possible to trace line of code, where this variable was first defined or modified?

It's all very useful and would save a lot of time for me.

I guess it's better to write own debugging window and output everything there, but would be awesome if such functionality already exist in some debugging tool.

Thanks again Adams. ^_=

I know i'm asking too much, but why this isn't implemented yet? O_o

Comment: No and No.  But you can set breakpoints where it is modified -- including conditional breakpoints.  As for the rest, you could join the Firebug team.  ;-)  Or at least submit a feature request.

Comment: PS.  Some of what you want may be provided by the `console.trace()` function.

Comment: Hmm, where to post request for new features? :)
Thanks i'll look into trace.

All could be easily fixed by adding possibility to log information to different(manually pointed), always on top, windows.

For example:
console.logTo(data,array(windowNumber/windowName,pin/unpin,grouped/ungrouped))

Comment: Hmm there are some functions like console.dir and console.group O_o
Haven't seen them earlier.